# Unicode works in mkii but not in mkiv

Tags: context, unicode

I have been using `texexec` which, as I understand it, is mkii. I have several documents that have unicode in them and typeset perfectly using `texexec`. However, `texexec` seems to have trouble with metapost and I would like to use mkiv. However, when I use `context` only a handful of the unicode characters actually typeset, namely the capital greek characters.

Any ideas why? How can I fix this?

**Example** In the following, the alpha typesets using `texexec` but not `context`.

```
\starttext
  α
\stoptext
```

Comment: A minimal example is needed. In general, ConTeXt MkIV handles unicode much better than MkII

Comment: @aditya I added an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default Latin modern fonts are used that do not have lower case greek. Use a full font like Times or Palatino or (if you need a CM look alike) CM Unicode. The following works fine:

```
\setupbodyfont[times]
\starttext
α
\stoptext
```

Comment: Actually, that didn't work. Still just a blank page. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @Doug: What version of ConTeXt you are using (`context --version`). For an older version, add `\usetypescript[times]` before `\setupbodyfont`. Is there any error message in the log?

Comment: That works. Thanks. Incidentally, what is the current version?

Comment: Actually, it only fixed some of the unicode (The greek alphabet). Is there no way to ensure that all unicode typesets?

Comment: @Doug: I am using `2011.09.10` version (8 days old), but there was a new release after that. To get the entire unicode alphabet, you need a font that coverts the entire alphabet (none AFAIK). So it depends on what you need. Most fonts have Latin, Greek, and Cyrillic; if you need that along with CJK (Chinese, Japanese, Korean), you need to set fallback to a different font using the `simplefonts` module; the same for Arabic; ConTeXt MkIV currently does not support font features of Indic scripts, so if you want that, then you will need to use xetex backend.

Comment: So, why does it work in mkii? I didn't really have to do anything special to get it to work. Most of the unicode I am using are mathematics symbols.

Comment: @Doug: Difficult to say without an example of what does not work (and knowing your context version).

Comment: @Doug I don't know context very much but I guess that the difference between mkii and mkiv is similar to the difference between (pdf)latex with inputenc and xelatex or lualatex: In the first cases non-ascii-chars are *commands* - commands which are carefully setup so that they grab the correct glyph (and if necessary switch to a sensible font). With xelatex/lualatex/mkiv non-ascii chars are no longer commands, they are simply passed to the font - and if the font doesn't have the glyph it can happen that nothing is printed (but imho context has some fallbacks methods implemented).